# Set Panel to display when CheckBox is checked? (Java)

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, checkbox, visibility

I have a checkbox and a panel. When the checkbox is checked, I would like for the panel to display. If the user un-checks it, I want the panel to go back to false visibility.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What GUI library are you using? What have you tried so far? And how does your current code attempt not work or what errors does it generate? If Swing, have you checked the tutorials for how JCheckBox's work as the solution is likely to be found right there?

Comment: Ah, I got it :) I had a simple mistake!

Comment: good deal! Keep on moving forward!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swing as the GUI toolkit. The solution is simple.

Below is the Swing implementation

```
private JCheckBox box;
box.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                jpanel.setVisible(box.isSelected());
            }
        });
```

Comment: no, you wouldn't use a changeListener. Instead use either an actionListener or an itemListener. Whichever you decide on, you can simplify the logic (even here) Hint: the value of condition used in the if is the same as the intended value of the visibility property :-)

Comment: Good answer @Chan